# Open keyboard on mount on mobile phone browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I get the input field to be focused and keyboard open to enter numbers.
At the moment I am getting this output when screen opens.

[image]

But I would love to get this one:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        required
        label="Required"
        defaultValue="Hello World"
        autoFocus={true}
        type="tel"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```